# Testing phpmailer without sending out emails

Tags: php, email, sendmail

I have phpmailer working on my system already. I am updating some code that uses it to send out emails, I just need to test to make sure that the update sends the correct information, but not send out actual emails as it sends them out to hundreds of people.

Is there a quick way to redirect phpmailer to a file, or better yet if phpmailer uses sendmail, to have that command redirect to a file? This is a test server, so it would be best if all mail functionality was redirected to a file or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set `sendmail_path` in php ini to whatever you want. For example, it can be `tee -a mail.log` so that everything gets logged to a file.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about the tee command, but it works great.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use MailHog

https://github.com/mailhog/MailHog

Just Setup MailHog In Your Application and just set configuration in your PHPMailer Like
Host => 'mail'
Port => 1025